# I'm trying to make a div background responsive in html using model image

Tags: html, css, django, django-models, django-templates

[want to make this responsive by using image as bg in HTML only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tMuQ.jpg)HTML file

I want to set model image as responsive background to main . adding CSS property like max-width is not working to div.
how to overlap bootstraps div?

```
    <div class="game-cover">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="about">
        <div class="row" style="background: url({{ game.game_cover.url }})">

            <div class="col-md-6 hidden-xs">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="game-header">
                    <h2 class="text-uppercase" style="color: whitesmoke"> {{ game.game_title }}  </h2>
                    <hr class="divider">
                </div>

                <div class="game-details">

                    <p class="text-justify" style="color: whitesmoke">{{ game.game_intro }}
                    </p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

what i want to do is this and make them overlap

```
<div class="game-cover">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="about">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ game.game_cover.url }}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 hidden-xs">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="game-header">
                    <h2 class="text-uppercase" style="color: whitesmoke"> {{ game.game_title }}  </h2>
                    <hr class="divider">
                </div>

                <div class="game-details">

                    <p class="text-justify" style="color: whitesmoke">{{ game.game_intro }}
                    </p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which elements do you want to overlap which other elements?

Comment: I want to overlap both col-md-6 sides by side on col-md-12 as col-md-12 is contains an image which I  want to use as background and responsive.